# Can I suppress MVC Client validation from running while programmatically changing input values?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation, asp.net-mvc-validation

I have a form where the input boxes are prefilled with default values. A jQuery event handler clears the value on 'focus' and restores the default value on 'blur', if the field is empty.

```
$('form input').on('focus blur', function (event) {
  var eventTarget = $(this);
  if (eventTarget.val() === eventTarget.data('default')
      || eventTarget.val() === '') {
    if (event.type === 'focus') {
      eventTarget.val('').removeClass('empty');
    } else {
      eventTarget.val(eventTarget.data('default')).addClass('empty');
    }
  }
}).trigger('blur');
```

Before submitting (via AJAX), I empty all fields that contain the default value and trigger client side validation (for required fields):

```
$('form').on('submit', function (e) {
  $('form input').each(function () {
      if ($(this).val() === $(this).data('default')) {
        $(this).val('');  // remove default value, so 'required' validation triggers on empty fields
      }
  });

  if ($('form').valid()) {
      $.ajax(...);
  } else {
    $('form input').trigger('blur');  // trigger 'blur' to restore default values
                                      // Problem: This clears the validation messages
  }
});
```

So far, so good, however after that, my form fields are of course empty. If I trigger the 'blur' event again, I can restore the default values, but that makes the validation messages disappear, probably because client side validation runs again and sees that the fields are no longer empty.

When I manually click in and out of the form field, though, the default value is restored and the validation message stays. Both go through the same 'blur' handler. I cannot figure out where the difference is.

**Edit:**
I have since figured out that I can disable validation on 'blur' completely:

```
$('form').validate().settings.onfocusout = false;
```

This works around my issue for now, but I would still like to know why blur/focusout reacts differently when triggered from a script or from user interaction.

Comment: It's difficult to understand what you're asking.  However, when using this plugin, you typically do not need a `submit` handler function.  There is a `submitHandler` callback function already built into the plugin and that is precisely where your `ajax` is supposed to be placed.

Comment: @Sparky: I've added comments in the code to hopefully make the issue clearer. Also, I am not invoking the validate plugin myself, but let MVC handle that. Therefore I don't know how I would register a `submitHandler`. Since the event triggers just fine as it is, I don't see how that would help me, anyway.